# Trouble getting Flash socket policy file to work

Tags: flash, file, policy

Basically I'm using Flash to connect to a Java server.

Despite my Java application replying to the `<policy-file-request/>`, in the Flash debug log it lists (not sure about the order as there are lots):

> *** Security Sandbox Violation ***
>
> Connection to 192.168.1.86:4049 halted
>   - not permitted from http://127.0.0.1:8888/Current/wander.swf
>
> Warning: Timeout on
>   xmlsocket://192.168.1.86:4049 (at 3
>   seconds) while waiting for socket
>   policy file.  This should not cause
>   any problems, but see
>   http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files
>   for an explanation.
>
> Error: Request for resource at
>   xmlsocket://192.168.1.86:4049 by
>   requestor from
>   http://127.0.0.1:8888/Current/wander.swf
>   is denied due to lack of policy file
>   permissions.

What I don't understand is, the server (port 4049) receives the request, outputs the policy file (appends null byte) and then closes the connection, surely it shouldn't time out?

**The policy file I'm using is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: "outputs the policy file (appends null byte) and then closes the connection". why do you close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex,
Two things you might additionally need to do. I don't think the specification actually states that you need to have these things in place, but I can't ever seem to get past socket policy file exceptions until I've done them.

1. Listen to `<policy-file-request/>` calls on port 843, and respond to them in the same way as you do on port 4049.
2. Put an http cross domain policy at `http://192.168.1.86/crossdomain.xml`

There are more details here: http://www.adobe.com/cn/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html

... but I guess you've already read that.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem, the perl server on port 843 tells me it's answered the request, but it still seems to timeout.

Comment: Are you terminating the packet you send back with a null byte (\0)? If not Flash's socket library doesn't detect the received message.

Comment: Unfortunately I am :/ somehow it is still timing out. Would it help if I moved the server app to another physical machine?

Comment: Stupid question, but thought I'd ask because it's important: your firewall isn't blocking incoming and outgoing communication on the port(s) you're using, right?

Comment: Yeah, also tried disabling it altogether. The policy server is definitely receiving the request as well.

Comment: Just tried a different policy server (port 843) which fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

In a 'howto' I've seen that the response must not contain the xml version tag. Just the cross-domain-policy tag.